# non significance of variables in my VAR estimate

Tags: regression, vector-autoregression

I am running a VAR model with 7 variables, but less than 10 out of 49 independent variables are significance. What could be the problem please?

Comment: Could you possibly provide more details about the situation you wants to be solved?

Comment: The problem is that almost all of the variables are not significant. I used VECM because they are cointegrated. Also, the R square of the model of interest is less than 50% which is worrisome.

Comment: The variables might have really no impact on the output. This can happen. Alternatively, you could try more complex nonlinear models to discover more complicated dependencies.

Comment: Additionally, if the R square is not zero, you are still capturing something. Your prediction is not very accurate, but still better than average of the output variables.

Comment: It is normal to have individually insignificant coefficients in a large VAR system. A model is almost always just an imperfect shot at the real underlying process. Even if the model was correct (which is very unlikely), you would expect approximately 5% of all coefficients to be insignificant (if your chosen significance level is 5%). If I were you, I would not worry too much about the the insignificant coefficients but rather pay closer attention to whether the model residuals are white noise and whether the AIC and BIC of the whole model are lower than that of a simpler benchmark model.